# Change seaborn.catplot marker colour brightness depending on values in pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, brightness

I try creating a `sns.catplot` chart out of a `pd.DataFrame` containing data of multiple bases (A, C, G, T, U<sup>1</sup> and U<sup>2</sup>).
My aim is to plot only the markers, which are brightness-dependent by the value of `df ['environment']`, so without lines or boxes or anything. I also tried several things with `cycler.cycler (color = colourlist)`, but ”the plot didn't want to choose“ more than three colours.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import cycler
import os

sns.set (style = 'white', color_codes = True, palette = ["#FF0000", "#0000FF", "#00FF00", "#C03030", "#3030C0", "#30C030"])

colourlist = np.array ([ [0, 0, 0] ])
for v in [0, 45] :
    for s in [0, 45] :
        for h in [0, 120, 240] :
            try :
                H, S, V = h / 360., (100 - s) / 100., (100 - v) / 100.
                colourlist = np.append (colourlist, [ [H, S, V] ], axis = 0)
            except :
                pass
colourlist = np.delete (colourlist, 0, 0)

matplotlib.rcParams ['axes.prop_cycle'] = cycler.cycler (color = colourlist)
matplotlib.rcParams ['image.cmap'] = 'hsv'
matplotlib.rcParams ['savefig.transparent'] = True
matplotlib.rcParams ['savefig.format'] = 'eps'
matplotlib.rcParams ['axes.xmargin'] = 0
matplotlib.rcParams ['axes.ymargin'] = 0
matplotlib.rcParams ['figure.frameon'] = False
matplotlib.spines.rcParams ['axes.spines.right'] = False
matplotlib.spines.rcParams ['axes.spines.top'] = False
matplotlib.rcParams ['xtick.bottom'] = True
matplotlib.rcParams ['ytick.left'] = True

file = os.path.join (os.environ ['HOME'], 'Data.csv')
with open (file, 'r') as f :
    df = pd.read_csv (f, index_col = 0, header = 0, thousands = None, decimal = '.')
df ['base'] = df ['base'].str.upper ()
#df ['method'] = df ['method'].str.upper ()
df = df.sort_values (['charge', 'base', 'environment'])

sns.catplot (jitter = False, data = df, x = 'base', y = 'energy', hue = 'charge', palette = ["#000FFF", "#00FF00", "#FF0000", "#00FFFF", "#FF00FF", "#FFFF00"], order = ['A', 'C', 'U1', '', 'G', 'T', 'U2'])
```

**~/Data.csv**:

```
,environment,base,charge,energy,method
0,pbs,A,neg,0.34835,1
1,pbs,C,neg,0.40194,2
2,pbs,G,neg,0.34959,1
3,pbs,T,neg,0.40738,2
4,pbs,U1,neg,0.34904,2
5,pbs,U2,neg,0.40016,2
6,pbs,A,neu,0.40151,3
7,pbs,C,neu,0.34494,3
8,pbs,G,neu,0.40193,3
9,pbs,T,neu,0.34458,3
10,pbs,U1,neu,0.34646,3
11,pbs,U2,neu,0.40871,3
12,pbs,A,pos,0.34047,2
13,pbs,C,pos,0.40157,2
14,pbs,G,pos,0.34232,2
15,pbs,T,pos,0.40854,2
16,pbs,U1,pos,0.34611,2
17,pbs,U2,pos,0.34414,2
18,polymeric,A,neg,0.28333,2
19,polymeric,C,neg,0.46908,3
20,polymeric,G,neg,0.33224,3
21,polymeric,T,neg,0.35825,1
22,polymeric,U1,neg,0.33033,3
23,polymeric,U2,neg,0.39167,3
24,polymeric,A,neu,0.36964,2
25,polymeric,C,neu,0.33979,2
26,polymeric,G,neu,0.41815,3
27,polymeric,T,neu,0.30786,2
28,polymeric,U1,neu,0.40727,1
29,polymeric,U2,neu,0.36719,3
30,polymeric,A,pos,0.38173,1
31,polymeric,C,pos,0.35060,3
32,polymeric,G,pos,0.37617,1
33,polymeric,T,pos,0.44172,2
34,polymeric,U1,pos,0.31267,3
35,polymeric,U2,pos,0.34478,2
```

I thought of something like

```
sns.scatterplot (data = df, x = 'base', y = 'energy', hue = 'charge', x_order = ['A', 'C', 'U1', '', 'G', 'T', 'U2'], brightness = np.where (df ['environment'] == 'pbs', 1., .5) ).
```

Could I also plot this (the data; `pandas.DataFrame`) with `matplotlib`? How could the code look like?

Comment: could you provide a mockup image of what you are trying to achieve? I don't understand what you mean by "brightness"?

Comment: @DizietAsahi It's supposed to be the s or v value of a hsv colour. I think the `alpha` would also do it, but not so well.